# Tkinter keyboard simulator

Tags: python, tkinter

I need the dif () function to compose text of different lengths from a dictionary depending on the complexity.
More precisely, I need to somehow change k when choosing the complexity.

```
def dif():
    global start_time
    message.pack()
    text_widget.pack()
    start_time = time.time()
    global test_text


with open("words.txt", "r") as words:
    test_words1 = choices(list(words), k)

    len_word_list = [len(word.strip()) for word in test_words1]

    index_nostrip1 = 6
    end_of_line1 = 0
    final_word_list1 = []
    lines_list1 = []
    line1 = ""

    for i in range(len(test_words1)):
        if end_of_line1 == index_nostrip1 - 1:
            final_word_list1.append(test_words1[i])
            line1 += test_words1[i].strip()
            lines_list1.append(line1)
            line1 = ""
            end_of_line1 = 0
        else:
            final_word_list1.append(test_words1[i].strip())
            line1 += f"{test_words1[i].strip()} "
            end_of_line1 += 1

    # create the final string to be used in the test
    test_text = " ".join(final_word_list1)

text_widget = Text(root, height=10, width=100,
                   padx=20, pady=20, font=("Arial ", 16))
text_widget.insert(END, test_text)
text_widget.configure(state="disabled")
text_widget.tag_config("correct", background="green", foreground="white")
text_widget.tag_config("wrong", background="red", foreground="white")


text_widget.bind("<KeyPress>", key_type)
text_widget.focus()
```

The command1 () function is executed if the start button is pressed

```
def command1():
    if var.get() == 0:
        k=10
        dif()
    elif var.get() == 1:
        k=15
        dif()
    elif var.get() == 2:
        k=20
        dif()
    root.deiconify()  
    top.destroy()
```

Comment: How exactly does title match the question? Also please provide a [mre]. Also I don't see Your attempts so what actually is the issue with the current code?

Comment: `dif` is not doing anything with text.  I would love to show you how to rewrite this correctly, but I can't tell what you are trying to do.

Comment: @TimRoberts,i want the k value to be selected in command1 ()

Comment: @EugeneSaitamovich well if You want to get an integer from user You could simply use what tkinter provides: `from tkinter.simpledialog import askinteger` and then call the function, the function returns an integer so place this function in the `command1()` function and assign it to a variable `k`, should be simple enough

Comment: Your say you need to 'change k' and `command1` is executed to start things? I notice  `k` is defined in `command1` but there is no `global` statement within `command1`.